# visibility of python output from bash

Tags: python, bash, docker

I've python code that includes tqdm code.
the bash build docker image and container however I can't see any output from the container(in CLI).

```
#!/bin/sh
docker build . -t traffic
docker run -d --name traffic_con traffic
docker wait traffic_con
docker cp -a traffic_con:/usr/TrafficMannager/out/data/. ./out/data/
docker rm /traffic_con
docker rmi /traffic
```

I've tried to run the container on interactive mode (-it) however it's throwing an error

[EDIT:]
Docker file:

```
FROM cityflowproject/cityflow

# Create a folder we'll work in 
WORKDIR /usr/TrafficMannager

# Upgrade installed packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean

# Install vim to open & edit code\text files
RUN apt-get install -y vim

# Install all python code depentences
RUN pip install gym && \
    pip install numpy && \
    pip install IPython && \
    pip install torch && \
    python -m pip install python-dotenv &&\
    pip install tqdm

COPY . .

CMD chmod u+x script/container_instructions.sh; ./script/container_instructions.sh
```

container_instructions:

```
#!/bin/sh
pip install lib/extern/CityFlow/.
python main.py
```

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile?

Comment: @clarj had been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the Docker container in the background, then immediately `docker wait` for it.  If you run the container in the foreground instead, you'll see its output on stdout, and the `docker run` command will complete when the container exits.

```sh
docker run --name traffic_con traffic  # without -d
```

Given the wrapper script you show, you may find this setup much easier to run in a Python virtual environment.  Ignore all the Docker parts and run:

```sh
python3 -m venv venv
./venv/bin/pip install gym numpy IPython torch python-dotenv tqdm lib/extern/CityFlow
./venv/bin/python3 main.py
```

The script will directly write to `./out/data` on the host system, without the long-winded privileged script to copy data out.

If you really do need a container here, you can also mount the output directory into the container to avoid the manual copy step.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
docker build . -t traffic
docker run --rm -v "$PWD/out/data:/usr/TrafficMannager/out/data" traffic
docker rmi traffic
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've removed -d and it worked. later I'll try your suggestions.
Cheers mate!